# How to cut an entire line in vim and paste it?

Tags: vim

I know how to use the `v` command in vim, but I need something which will delete an entire line and it should allow me to paste the same line somewhere else.

Comment: You should update your accepted answer. It doesn't tell you how to paste...

Comment: To move a line say from line 10 to line 20 use the following   :10m 20

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> would select that entire line and pressing <kbd>d</kbd> would delete it.

You can also use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, which is does not require you to enter visual mode.

Comment: Or you could press vv, or dd, which are equivalent without the annoying visual mode activating.

Comment: `dd` easier than `shift + v` -> `d`

Comment: what about undo... Im trying on my docs and not able to undo them.

Comment: What about paste??

Comment: @becko `Shift` + `P`

Comment: @becko `p` Paste after cusror `Shift` + `P` Paste before cursor. Accepted answer is terrible. Shouldn't have to answer in comments.

Comment: @KolobCanyon Totally agree. I will edit the answer :). 
Update: errrgh. "Suggested edit queue is full."

Answer (score 506):

`dd` in command mode (after pressing escape) will cut the line, `p` in command mode will paste.

Update:

For a bonus, `d` and then a movement will cut the equivalent of that movement, so `dw` will cut a word, `d<down-arrow>` will cut this line and the line below, `d50w` will cut 50 words.

`yy` is copy line, and works like `dd`.

`D` cuts from cursor to end of line.

If you've used `v` (visual mode), you should try `V` (visual line mode) and `<ctrl>v` (visual block mode).

Comment: Good answer. I would add `P` to paste the line before the cursor in command mode. And `<Ctrl-R>"` to paste the line in insert mode.

Comment: And `]p` to paste with correct indenting. But we should be careful not to post the entire vim manual here :).

Answer (score 50):

**Delete current line and copy to clipboard:**

<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

---

**Paste After The Cursor**

<kbd>p</kbd>

---

**Paste Before The Cursor**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

---

**Select Whole Line** (I use this ALL the time)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

Then <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> to move down and up respectively

---

Essentially <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> is the equivalent of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: Does *SHIFT + P* insert before or after the current line, where the cursor is located?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I've updated my answer to answer your question. `Shift` + `p` will paste before the cursor. I find myself using just plain `p` more often these days.

Answer (score 16):

There are several ways to cut a line, all controlled by the `d` key in normal mode. If you are using visual mode (the `v` key) you can just hit the `d` key once you have highlighted the region you want to cut. Move to the location you would like to paste and hit the `p` key to paste.

It's also worth mentioning that you can copy/cut/paste from registers. Suppose you aren't sure when or where you want to paste the text. You could save the text to up to 24 registers identified by an alphabetical letter. Just prepend your command with `'` (single quote) and the register letter (a thru z). For instance you could use the visual mode (`v` key) to select some text and then type `'ad` to cut the text and store it in register 'a'. Once you navigate to the location where you want to paste the text you would type `'ap` to paste the contents of register a.

Answer (score 16):

Let's say that you wanted to cut the line `bbb` and paste it under the line `---`

Before:

```
aaa
bbb
---
```

After:

```
aaa
---
bbb
```

1. Put your cursor on the line `bbb`
2. Press <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
3. Put your cursor on the line `---`
4. Press <kbd>p</kbd>

[image]

Comment: How did you do that video? Is that just a `.gif`?

Comment: @KolobCanyon It is an animated GIF created with LICEcap - https://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Answer (score 13):

The quickest way I found is through editing mode:

1. Press `yy` to copy the line.
2. Then `dd` to delete the line.
3. Then `p` to paste the line.

Comment: Does *p* insert before or after the current line, where the cursor is located?

Comment: It pastes after the line where the cursor is located

Answer (score 11):

1. press 'V' in normal mode to select the entire line
2. then press 'y' to copy it
3. go to the place you want to paste it and press 'p' to paste after cursor or 'P' to paste before it.

Answer (score 7):

Yep, use dd in command line. Also I recommend to print useful image with ViM hotkeys available at http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Answer (score 6):

**Just three steps.**

---

1. Go to the **start** of the text, and press <kbd>v</kbd>
2. Go to the **end** of the text, and press <kbd>d</kbd>
3. Go to the place that you want **to paste**, and press <kbd>p</kbd>

---

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the line, and first press `esc`, and then `Shift + v`.

(This would have highlighted the line)

2. press `d`

(The line is now deleted)

3. Go to the location, where you wanted to paste the line, and hit `p`.

In a nutshell,

`Esc` -> `Shift + v` -> `d` -> `p`